# RFID ReaderTrack Loop

Tags: java, sockets, rfid

Hey guys i'll like to do the project call "RFID Management System"

I found some samlpe code from some websites and add a few codes into it.

My RFID can read the number from mifare card right now, but I Already face the problem : How to create a loop for my RFID machine in order to read the card again and again without pushing the "RUN" button in Eclipse

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.smartcardio.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Blog {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   // Display the list of terminals
   TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
   List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
   System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);

   // Use the first terminal
   CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);

   // Connect wit hthe card

   Card card = terminal.connect("*");
   System.out.println("card: " + card);
   CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();


   // Send Select Applet command
   ResponseAPDU answer = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(new byte[] { (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00 } ));

   // Send test command
   answer = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(new byte[] { (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00 } ));
   byte r[] = answer.getData();
   String hex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(answer.getBytes());
   System.out.println("Response: " + hex);

   // Disconnect the card
   card.disconnect(false);
  } catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Ouch: " + e.toString());
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U might be aware of arduino programming , right?, there we have a loop function(), so whatever code we write inside it loops for ever. That is the logic for these things (like rfid, finger print scanner, temp sensors, motion detectors etc) . So use the same technology here. Put ur code inside a

```
while(1){

 }
```

loop. 
This will iterate ur code for ever. hence u will get the desired o/p. U can flash ur card as many times as u want.
Make sure that the code for reading and processing the data should only come inside the loop. Otherwise it takes much memory and may crash ur code.